# How can I create a Sharepoint List Item with related Terms/Taxononmy

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The problem is that is not clear, in the docs, how to set these values in the payload.  Is clear that from the UI you obviously can, but using the Graph API doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to create a List Item, but is not clear to me how to provide the TermGuid.

I've tried something like this:

```py
payload = {
    "fields": {
         "Title": "My item",
         "CustomMetadataField": {
              "TermGuid": "[uuid]"
         }
    }

}
```

But I always get a 400 error.

I also tried something like this:

```py
payload = {"fields": {"CustomMetaDataField": "-1;#Label|uuid"}}
```

None of that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly set the value of your managed metadata field, but you need to set the value of **the hidden column name** associated with the managed metadata field.

List all columns included the hidden columns

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns?$select=id,name,hidden,displayName
```

The response looks like this

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "displayName": "ManagedMetadata",
      "hidden": false,
      "id": "062e47e1-021e-4b11-9632-61c8968209a7",
      "name": "ManagedMetadata"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "ManagedMetadata_0",
      "hidden": true,
      "id": "08be9a90-5e7a-404e-b5f8-77121d7973c3",
      "name": "g62e47e1021e4b11963261c8968209a7"
    }
  ]
}
```

Suppose that the `name` of the field in UI is **ManagedMetadata**. This field has a hidden field with the `displayName` **ManagedMetadata_0** and the `name` **g62e47e1021e4b11963261c8968209a7** to be used in a `POST` request.

```
POST /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
{
    "fields": {
        "{hidden_field_name}": "{TermGuid}"
    }
}
```

Where `{hidden_field_name}` in this case is **g62e47e1021e4b11963261c8968209a7**. The value is either `{TermGuid}` or `-1;{TermName}|{TermGuid}`.

Comment: That worked! Although sometimes the right field could be `ManagedMetadata_1`, not sure why.